Is there anyway to delete a private endpoint which is in disconnected stage using powershell/cli?
Can you delete a private endpoint which is in disconnected state using powershell, I tried the command Remove-AzPrivateEndpoint -Name MyPrivateEndpoint1 -ResourceGroupName TestResourceGroup
Apparently it works when the privateendpoint is in connected state, I am trying to find a way to do it using azure powershell/CLI


Is there anyway to delete a private endpoint which is in disconnected stage using powershell/cli?

Here is the PowerShell script checks the state of the PrivateEndpoint before deletion; if the PrivateEndpoint is connected, it will not be deleted
    $privateEndpoint = Get-AzPrivateEndpoint -Name "venkat-endpoint" -ResourceGroupName "RG_Name"
    
    if ($privateEndpoint -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "Private endpoint not found."
    } else {
        $endpointstate = $privateEndpoint.PrivateLinkServiceConnectionsText | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PrivateLinkServiceConnectionState | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Status
    
        if ($endpointstate -eq 'Disconnected') {
            
            Write-Host "Private endpoint name : venkat-endpoint is in : $endpointstate state"
           
            Remove-AzPrivateEndpoint -Name "venkat-endpoint" -ResourceGroupName "v-vallepuv-Mindtree" -Force
    
            Write-Host "Private endpoint deleted successfully."
    
        } else {
            Write-Host "Private endpoint is not in a disconnected state. Current state: Connected"
        }
    }

Private endpoint is disconnected state.

After running the script, the Private endpoint is successfully deleted when its state is set to disconnected.


Thanks @Venkat V, I tried the same, not sure why it worked now, and it did not before, probably might've messed up param names, thank you for this! :)

There may be a syntax issue in your script.
